# sqoop not import datatype varchar2 from oracle 9i to hadoop

Tags: hadoop, import, hdfs, sqoop, oracle9i

sqoop not import datatype varchar2 from oracle 9i to hadoop

I have a table in oracle 9i and I want send the information to hdfs.

I am trying to do ir with sqoop, but varchar2 columns are not imported. I mean

that these data isn't arriving to hdfs file, therefore I can't see it in my

hive table

could anybody help me please?

Comment: Share your Hive import command